# Validate URLs in nodejs + express to handle bad request errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, http

Well, after reading some things about this issue, i decide to ask about.

The idea is simple in the core: detect incoming invalid URL's/URI's and return a response to the client with the pertinent code/data.

Normally, when treat the errors in node, we use syntax like:

```
if (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(error: {msg: err.message, stack: err.stack});
}
```

Okay, that is pretty simple but the essential thing is that we detect: **"hey, if an error occurs, shoot this thing to the client"**.

But what if it's not an 500 internal? As i know, bad request errors are send like a client error and have their own stack, type and message in the prompt, rigth?

Reading [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), i found the URIError constructor, that points to an instance representing an error that occurs with ivalids URI's. So, it's possible to make some like this:

```
if (err instanceof URIError) { /* send a handler for bad request */ };
```

Or i need to validate from scratch the URI and make my own error inheritance?

Any hint? Idea? ... Thanks in advance! <3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually do this by defining the routes I want:

```
app.get('/good' ... );
app.post('/alsogood' ... );
```

And then to catch unrouted urls, do:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    throw new Error("Bad request")
})
```

And then inject an error handling middleware:

```
app.use(function(e, req, res, next) {
    if (e.message === "Bad request") {
        res.status(400).json({error: {msg: e.message, stack: e.stack}});
    }
});
```

You can obviously get a lot more complex than this, but this simple idea gets the point across.

Also, for what it's worth, you should probably throw a 404 back to to the client if they're trying to access a URL that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm, i don't get the thing rigth now. You are defining **all** routes to be a bad request (?)... exactly how you know if a URL is bad formated?

Sorry, i'm pretty new in this stuff

Comment: No, define the routes you know about first - those will be routed to their appropriate controllers. But if someone sends a request that doesn't have a route handler, then you throw the 400. If you were to paste all of that code into a new file and run it, you'll see what happens when you hit `/good`, `/alsogood`, and `/bad`. You could also use the same mechanism to throw a new error anywhere in your controllers as well.

Comment: OH! I got it, is reaally simple! ... thanks for that!